# CWAC Camera - Movable CameraView after zoom

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

With CWAC-Camera, how could I implement a movable camera view after a zoom takes place?  For example, double tap to zoom in to some set zoom value, then drag around within the cameraview to move the preview to the bounds of the entire data being captured by the Camera (that is outside of the preview after zooming)

Comment: "double tap to zoom in to some set zoom value" -- ordinarily, I would say use `zoomTo()` on your `CameraFragment` or `CameraView`. However, while you say "zoom", that's not really what you are asking for. "then drag around within the cameraview to move the preview to the bounds of the entire data being captured by the Camera (that is outside of the preview after zooming)" -- that's not "zoom". Zoom is a camera feature, sometimes implemented in physical hardware (e.g., optical zoom on Samsung Galaxy Camera).

Comment: Near as I can tell, what you are asking to do is to stretch the preview pane to be beyond the bounds of the screen, then be able to pan around and move the screen as a viewport on that larger `View`. I assume that this is possible. However, it does not really have anything to do with my library. Whatever technique you would use to do that with an `ImageView` should work, at least with a `TextureView`-based preview, and possibly also with a `SurfaceView`-based preview.